# Excel if Command

Tags: excel

I want to tell excel to do the following in a single cell:

```
##IF T2=1 AND there is any number both in E2 and F2, THEN Sum(C2:F2) - 4, BUT IF T2 =1, but F2 is empty THEN sum(C2:E2) – 3, ALSO, IF T2 = 1, but both E2 and F2 are empty THEN sum(C2:D2) – 2, FINALLY, IF T2=0, THEN C2 – 1##
```

Comment: What if E2 is empty and F2 has number?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I don't have such a thing in the command I presented with my question?

Comment: That is why I asked.  If there will never be a time that E2 will be empty and F2 will have a number then the answer below will work for you.

Comment: Your command below works and thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
=IF(T2=0,C2-1,SUM(C2:F2)-COUNT(C2:F2))
```

[image]